# Path Animation of CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, animation, path, cashapelayer

I have drawn quarter circle. For that I used center of UIView as centre. Drawing part is fine.
Now I want to animate it on path. So I used KeyFrame animation.
The problem is it is rotating on center of CAShapeLayer. That I don't want. I want to rotate cgpath around border. See in initial position, it is correct. But when started rotating on path, it is taking center of CAShapeLayer and then rotating on path.

Here is code for yellow quarter:

```
     CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
     CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2, 100, (0), (M_PI_2), NO);
     CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2, 100-50, (M_PI_2), (0), YES);
     CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
     CAShapeLayer* arcLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc]init];
     arcLayer.path = path;
     arcLayer.frame = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path);
     arcLayer.fillColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
     arcLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
     arcLayer.bounds = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path);
```

I am staring animation on single tap gesture.Here is code for animation :

```
   - (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
     CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:self];
     NSArray* subLayerArray = [pathLayer sublayers];
     for (int i = 0; i < subLayerArray.count; i++) {
     CAShapeLayer* layer = [subLayerArray objectAtIndex:i];
     if(CGPathContainsPoint(layer.path, NULL, touchPoint, NO)){
        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2, 100, 0,  3*M_PI/2, NO);
        CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        anim.path = path;
        anim.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAutoReverse;
        anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        anim.duration = 100.0;
        [layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@""];
        }
     }
   }
```

[image: Initial postion]
[image: during rotaion]

Comment: Don't ask the same question again. If you have more information, edit your existing question

Answer (score 0):

Yes finally i got the solution.We do not forget about anchorPoint of layer.Here i need to set anchorPoint.`arcLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0 , 1);`.
Hope this will help you...